# Strange 'if()' expression in AspectJ pointcut

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

When I read the source code, I saw a piece of code like this. Can someone help me explain what it means?

```java
@AfterReturning(
      pointcut = "(args(value) && (call(java.lang.String.new(java.lang.String)) && if(void java.lang.Object.if_())))",
      returning = "returnObject",
      argNames = "value,returnObject"
   )
```

Comment: This question is still listed as unanswered, even though I wrote an answer. Please inspect my answer, then either accept and upvote it or comment on it if you do not understand it. You asked for help, I tried to help. I think this deserves feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the `if` clause is just nonsense. In native AspectJ, it would not even compile according to the [syntax description](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697) in the AspectJ manual.

I would hope that your IDE and the Spring runtime display errors too.

Does the aspect using this pointcut even work at all? If so, does its behaviour change in any way, if you remove the bogus `if` clause?